# Multiple Select value saving Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, save, meta

i make meta box and in this i make select option with multiple

```
$opt_meta_author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true);

<select name="opt_meta_author" id="opt_meta_author" multiple="multiple">
    <?php
        $auth_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'author',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $authors = new WP_Query($auth_args);

        while($authors->have_posts()) :
            $authors->the_post();
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo the_title() ?>">
            <?php echo the_title() ?>
        </option>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
</select>
```

when i select multiple options it save only one option, i want to save selected options

is there any suggestions

Saving meta values

```
$opt_meta_author = $_POST['opt_meta_author'];
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', $opt_meta_author);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$opt_meta_author = unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true));

<select name="opt_meta_author" id="opt_meta_author" multiple="multiple">
                <?php
                    $auth_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'author',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC'
                    );
                $authors = new WP_Query($auth_args);

                while($authors->have_posts()) :
                    $authors->the_post();
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo the_title() ?>">
                        <?php echo the_title() ?>
                    </option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </select>
```

To get multiple selected value while storing do this:

```
$opt_meta_author = serialize($_POST['opt_meta_author']);
```

Comment: Nothing happen it gives my only this - s:6:"Nadeem";

Comment: @deemi.exe If you select multiple then it will be passed as array to the server, and you have to serialize before saving to database.

Comment: i do this

$opt_meta_author = serialize($_POST['opt_meta_author']);
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', $opt_meta_author);

Comment: when i save with multiple select values, it gives me only one value

Answer (score 1):

What is the `var dump` of `$_POST['opt_meta_author'])`? if it is an array, convert it in string using `implode` and save the string in database

Comment: This is a string, can u tell me how to save in db

Comment: I guess `update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', $opt_meta_author);` should work on saving in databases

Comment: Thanx alot man i use implode and its work but one mistake i did is <select name="opt-meta_author">, and do this <select name="opt-meta_author[]"> and its work fine with implode()